# In concurrent code, should a mutex and the data it protects be kept close together in memory, or far apart?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, mutex

Should the data and the mutex be in the same cache line?
Does it depend on how frequently the data is going to be updated? I am guessing that if we update the data infrequently, we could still frequently access the mutex just to access the data. In such cases, we don't want to load the data in the cache every time we load the mutex. On the other hand, if we frequently modify the data, then I would imagine that it makes more sense to load the data and mutex together in the cache? I could not find a definitive answer through a web search - hence the question.